# On submit get button's value

Tags: php, html, post

Im with a problem..
When i click in a normal button, for example `<input type="button" value="1">`, he executes the form and i don't wanna do that way.
What i need?

I need, when i submit the form, he will get the value of the button with a simple POST method.
Im using this at the moment:

```
<form method="post">
       <button name="list_items_qt" value="16">
       <button name="list_items_qt" value="32">
       <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

In summary, i just need to post the value of the button that i selected before!
Sorry for the bad english!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<form method="post">` if an action to a file is not included, it defaults to "self". Do you have any PHP to go with that, or are you asking us to write it for you? Plus, this `<button name="list_items_qt" value="16">` use `<button type="submit" name="list_items_qt" value="16">` etc.

Comment: Give your button a name?

Comment: It is self-paged, but, in the beginning i just do $_POST['submit']..

Comment: I dont want to submit TROUGH out the button, but i want to submit with the input TYPE submit!

Comment: normally a button will launch the form. You can use a button type button (html tag) to avoid that

Comment: Change both of the `button` tags to submit buttons with a value and see which you got? If not, you need to go through Javascript

Comment: Ok, so why the extra 2x buttons? That's what I don't understand. What is it exactly that you want to do, get the value of both buttons when you click on the "submit" button?

Comment: You're not understanding the point!
I have two buttons, fine! When i click on submit, i want the value of the button that i previosly SELECTED!

Comment: @Linkz a button isn't selected. Is Clicked.

Comment: Finally someone is helping!
Thanks marco!
And i need to do it some kind of this way, what you advise?

Comment: $value = $_POST['list_items_qt'];

Comment: @Linkz That said, put one input type hidden for each button, onclick on button 1 set a value on hidden input 1. Then, on form submission you will see the value.

Comment: @MarcoMura Im understanding, but can you show me a sneak of the code in order to acomplish that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery

```
<form method="post">
       <button name="list_items_qt_1" value="16" id="list_items_qt_1">
       <button name="list_items_qt_2" value="32" id="list_items_qt_2">
       <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var btn1 = $('#list_items_qt_1').val();
        var btn2 = $('#list_items_qt_1').val();

        alert(btn1+=+btn2);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

(i'll do it for 1 button)
i'm using Jquery here.

```
<form method="post">
       <input id="btn1" type="hidden" name="btn1" value=""/>
       <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<button id="list_items_qt" onClick="btn1()">

<script>
function btn1(){
$('#btn1').val('32');
}
</script>
```

Then on page form you can find

```
$_POST['btn1'];
```

The code is untested and is an example.

Comment: That's exacly what i needed!
Thank you so much Marco! :)